# Networked machine cannot be access via ip in a browser

Tags: windows-7, networking, php

I have a windows 7 machine that i have recently added php/apache/mysql etc and all works fine locally (localhost etc).  But what i really want to do now is to access it from several more pc/macs on our work network.

How can i do so so that when i type in the machines network IP (192.168.1.53) it will work as if i am accessing localhost directly form the machine.

I can connect to the computer via my mac but this gives me access to the usual user folders etc.

My php and files are on the C drive and the webserver files are in the apache24/htdocs folder but using the connect to server gives me no access to this folder?

Any help appreciated

**FURTHER UPDATE**

i have managed to repoint the C:/Apache24/htdocs folder to C:.../Desktop/Sites folder.  Running localhost/test.php works and displays within the browser of the machine.

I have also set up a virtual host name phpserve.local and set up the host files etc on the local machine so going to phpserve.local will yield the same as localhost/127.0.0.1 etc

But the issue is now to get the other machines to do the same when visiting 192.168.1.53/??

Its seems visiting this on other computers (macs and PC) using the ip 192.168.1.53 does not work and just fails. Cannot connect this seems to be the issue now rather than the setting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order for me to have executed the ip etc form other networked computers i had to turn on the web port 80 access within my firwall (mcAfee security one).